# ASP.NET Core - background service - will async tasks stop if app is closed unexpectedly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task, background-service

I'm curious about a fact whether if I run two asynchronous tasks in background service by way described below, if these tasks will be cancelled if there will be unexpected error in application and the whole application will close. I saw [on microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) an article about background services and there were below paragraphs:

If the app shuts down unexpectedly (for example, the app's process fails), StopAsync might not be called. Therefore, any methods called or operations conducted in StopAsync might not occur.

The hosted service is activated once at app startup and gracefully shut down at app shutdown. If an error is thrown during background task execution, Dispose should be called even if StopAsync isn't called.

My code in background service is like below:

```
    private Task _inactiveUsers;
    private Task _unconfirmedUsers;

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        LoggerHelper.LoggerHelper.Info("UserManagement service - starting to execute tasks.");
        _inactiveUsers = GetRidOfInactiveUsers(stoppingToken);
        _unconfirmedUsers = GetRidOfUnconfirmedUsers(stoppingToken);

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && (!_inactiveUsers.IsCompleted || !_unconfirmedUsers.IsCompleted))
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000,stoppingToken);
        }
        LoggerHelper.LoggerHelper.Info("UserManagement service - stopping to execute tasks.");
    }
```

Methods GetRidOfInactiveUsers and GetRidOfUnconfirmedUsers below:

```
private async Task GetRidOfInactiveUsers(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //some logic
                await Task.Delay(setup.MsToSleep, cancellationToken);
            }
}

private async Task GetRidOfUnconfirmedUsers(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // some logic
        await Task.Delay(setup.MsToSleep, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Dispose method:

```
    public override void Dispose()
    {
        if (_inactiveUsers != null)
            _inactiveUsers.Dispose();

        if (_unconfirmedUsers != null)
            _unconfirmedUsers.Dispose();

        base.Dispose();
    }
```

If there's expected shutdown of the app, cancellation token's property `IsCancellationRequested` is changed to `True` and `Task.Delay` with a cancellation token as a parameter will stop waiting and thus both methods (`GetRidOf...`) should successfully finish so as `ExecuteAsync` am I right? Or should I also implement `StopAsync` method anyway?

And how to ensure tasks will be 'closed' and won't remain running after the app closes unexpectedly?

Comment: For graceful shutdowns, this should be fine according to the docs, as long as both tasks finish quickly enough (if you have more async calls inside, ensure you pass the token). For forced shutdowns (like the process being manually killed) there's obviously nothing you can do, code will stop executing immediately

Comment: There is *always* a chance that your application will shutdown unexpectedly and your `Dispose` method will never be called. If the app closes, nothing will be running. It can't keep on processing data just because it's running on a task.

Comment: It is my understanding that all running tasks are aborted once the process that owns them ends. It seems like you don't have the chance to exit those threads "cleanly" given an unexpected crash.